# Read data from pdf file using php

Tags: php, pdf

I read pdf file using the code in this link  http://webcheatsheet.com/php/reading_clean_text_from_pdf.php .My pdf file contain a table structure, but after reading the file all data messed up like xxx 333 Exited from Country 26-01-2014 yyy 444 Entered to Country 26-01-2014 zzz 555 Exited from Country 26-01-2014

My pdf structure is

visaNo  Name    date             Type

333    xxx     26-01-2014       Existed from country
 
 444    yyy     26-01-2014       Entered to country
 
 555    zzz      26-01-2014      Existed from country

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm afraid there's no easy fix for this.
In the pdf source code the order in which you write down the bits of text is not important, since you can give all of them specific cohordinates.
The two things you can do are (imho):

1. [In any case] Change your code to give you the text streams separated (maybe replacing Tj and TJ with a special character of your choice, instead of throwing them away)
2. If you are extremely sure that the software generating the pdf file acts consistently, switch by hand the columns (the cells will be separated by your special character)
3. If not I'm afraid you will have to change your code a little bit more and take care of the cohordinates of all the text streams and guess from them the row# and the col# of your text stream.

I really hope for you there is some php class doing this